# WPF Progressbar Rectangle

Tags: wpf

I am using the following `ProgressBar` `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Grid MinHeight="14"  MinWidth="400" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Border x:Name="PART_Track" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF" />
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="2"  BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0,-1,0,1">
                    <Grid ClipToBounds="True" x:Name="Animation">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     Fill="#3399FF" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>                    
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040"/>
</Style>
```

It's working fine but I want to display three rectangles with different colors at a time (Left, Center, Right) as the indicator part, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Where exactly would you like to display the three rectangles? A picture would really help here. But if you want to change the indicator part to three rectangles, then simply add two more to your Animation Grid.

Comment: I want to change indicator part to three rectangles, in animation grid when i was add two more rectangles in grid then new added rectangles defined colors not moved like "PART_GlowRect". I want to move three colors (left,center,right) simultaneously in progress bar, like currently move one color. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should change your `PART_GlowRect` to be a `Border` instead of a `Rectangle`, and add the desired rectangles inside that:

```
<Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="2"  BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0,-1,0,1">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="True" x:Name="Animation">
        <Border x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red"  />
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Green" />
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Blue" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

This is how it will look like:

[image: progressbar]