# How to customize “indeterminate” mode in progress bar?

Tags: wpf, xaml

**My Goal:**
Stripped progressbar animating continuously exactly same as:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eadZY.gif)

**What i have tried:**
I tried solution from this link:
[WPF Progressbar Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426646/wpf-progressbar-rectangle)

```
<Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="2"  BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0,-1,0,1">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="True" x:Name="Animation">
        <Border x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red"  />
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Green" />
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Blue" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

See results in attached image below:

[image]

I would appreciate the help and also want solution for this in pure XAML only if possible. Thanks.

Comment: _"The problem with this approach is that i have to add rectangles manually"_ On the "My goal" picture I don't see any rectangles, except the one - progress bar.

Comment: @Rekshino what i mean by rectangle is that present in ControlTemplate of progressbar

Comment: What do you mean by "Stripped"? Do you want to remove animation of ProgressBar?

Comment: @emoacht stripped progressbar = bootstrap 4 stripped animating progressbar. But, in XAML WPF.

Comment: @JunaidShaikh Ahh, you mean "Striped". If so, I think the answer you referred will not be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create strips by adding `DrawingBrush` with `TileMode=Tile` and then animate them by changing `X` value of its `Viewport` property using RectAnimation when the ProgressBar is  IsIndeterminate state.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Progress" Color="#FF1C61F3"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Stripe" Color="#33FFFFFF"/>

<Style x:Key="StripedProgressBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Progress}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <RectAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Stripe"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(TileBrush.Viewport)"
                                                   Duration="0:0:1"
                                                   From="0,0,20,20" To="-20,0,20,20"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                          ClipToBounds="true"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Stripe"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="Uniform"
                                              Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Stripe}">
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <PathGeometry>
                                                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                                        <PathFigureCollection>
                                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                <LineSegment Point="5,0"/>
                                                                <LineSegment Point="10,5"/>
                                                                <LineSegment Point="10,10"/>
                                                            </PathFigure>
                                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,5">
                                                                <LineSegment Point="5,10"/>
                                                                <LineSegment Point="0,10"/>
                                                            </PathFigure>
                                                        </PathFigureCollection>
                                                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                                                </PathGeometry>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                </DrawingBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Stripe" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: I don't have words to thank you. You really understood and your solution is exactly what i wanted. Thanks alot. 