# Custom Indeterminate Rectangle Progress Bar in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I need to create a progress bar as below gif

[image]

But I am not able to create that kind of Progress bar so i referred the below link

[WPF Progressbar Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426646/wpf-progressbar-rectangle)

```
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid MinHeight="14"  MinWidth="400" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Track" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF" />
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="2" Width="200" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0,-1,0,1">
                            <Grid ClipToBounds="True" x:Name="Animation">
                                <Border x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red"  />
                                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Green" />
                                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Blue" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040"/>
    </Style>
```

The output of the above code looks like this

[image]

I tired the above code but here, After every rectangular color (i.e. red, green, blue) passes from left to right there will black color for 2 sec after that every rectangular color comes from left, I want to remove the black color so only rectangular colors should move from left to right.